# Creating new dictionary when saving data to plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist

So I am saving 3 NSStrings from 3 UITextFields to a property list. This works fine, but everytime I save something new, the app overwrites the data that was saved before. So basically there is only 1 Dictionary used, but i want the app to create a new dictionary everytime i save something new, so that no data gets deleted. I have no Idea how i could do this, so please help me!! :)

Code:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3];
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil]; 
        [array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab1.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab2.text], nil] forKeys:keys]]; 
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
        [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've got it:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

    NSLog(@"path='%@'",path);

    NSFileManager *nfm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    if([nfm fileExistsAtPath:path])
    {

        // if file exists, get its contents, add more entries and write back

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"4",@"5",@"6",nil]; 
        [array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab1.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab2.text], nil] forKeys:keys]]; 
        NSLog(@"modified array=%@",array);
        BOOL ok = [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        if(!ok){
            NSLog(@"Unable to write appended file");
            return;
        }

    } else {

        // if file doesn't exist, create a new one

        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil]; 
        [array addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab1.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lab2.text], nil] forKeys:keys]]; 
        NSLog(@"new array=%@",array);
        BOOL ok = [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
        if(!ok){
            NSLog(@"Unable to write new file");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a NSMutableArray to which you add each new dictionary object and then write that array to data.plist.

Comment: i dont really understand it, could you please give me some code?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you alloc the array with capacity?  I would just use `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]`, then add your objects.

Also, I had trouble saving `NSMutableDictionaries` in the `NSUserDefaults`, so what I ended up doing was just saving the dictionary to a file with

```
[dict writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
```

and `initWithContentsOfFile` or `initWithContentsOfURL` depending if I wanted to load a local or Internet file.

I should add, you can writeToFile, initWithContentsOf* for NSMutableArray as well.

Comment: I have tried to follow what you have said, but without sucsess. I think i didnt understand everything of what you said, could you please take the code that i have provided and modify it, so that you think it will be right? thank you

Comment: `initWithCapacity:` is fine to use if you know the capacity beforehand (but you're initializing with 3 and only using 1 - no harm, but unneeded)

Comment: ok but if i do [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] nothing changes.

Comment: First of all, you only add one object to the array.  That object is a NSDictionary that contains an array of 3 strings.  The code you have above just instantiates the top-level array and saves it to a file.  If you do `NSLog(@"%@", path);` on the send-to-last line, then run that in the simulator, you can open the file from the Finder and view its contents - a simple XML file.  Use that to visually verify it is saving what you expect.  I just copy/paste the path from the gdb debugger output console into the "Go To Folder" dialog in the Finder.